# Additional meaning of the word "fletcher"

Tags: meaning, metaphors

I am translating English wiki for Habitica game into Russian, and I am not sure what the word "fletchers" means in the following **context** ([the article about contributor titles](http://habitica.wikia.com/wiki/Contributor_Titles)):

> "Title: Fletchers; Description: Labor to make a transportable Habitica app, like Blacksmiths, working programming wizardry in unseen layers of Habitica."

It is quite difficult to **connect** this "**fletchers**" with 
1) someone making arrows (mobile app and arrows?); 
2) any famous people with this surname (no programmers among them).

The only more or less close meaning have been found in [Urban Dictionary](http://ru.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fletcher) with meaning "***a guy that is doing smth good***". However, I am still not satisfied, and I'd like to know what native speakers think of it.

Comment: fetchers or fLetchers?  You've got both in your question.

Comment: I am sorry for this typo, it is, of course, "fLetchers"

Comment: Sense 1 is yours. Fletchers put the feathers that provide stability and allow targeting onto arrows, so "transportable". Its a reach, but that's the sense.

Comment: There is the use of "fletcher" in minced oaths.  "Mother fletcher" is a common one, though a bit archaic.

Comment: Much like Blacksmiths programming on a forge to make the world, it sounds like it's using a fletcher making virtual arrows in the form of mobile apps

Answer (score 2):

Just to give a formal answer to this old question, I want to affirm JEL's comment that "Fletchers put the feathers that provide stability and allow targeting onto arrows, so 'transportable'." Like blacksmiths, fletchers are a tad old-timey, but that seems to suit the tenor of the game in question.

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) offers this brief entry for *fletcher*:

> **fletcher** (14c) : a maker of arrows

Elsewhere, the *Eleventh Collegiate* reports that the verb *fletch*, meaning to "feather," as in to "*fletch* an arrow," is a seventeenth-century back formation from *fletcher*.

Comment: But it should be noted that the quoted line appears to be referring to a term of jargon in computer gaming, only figuratively related (if that) to the arrow-making meaning.

Comment: It looks to me like it is not a term of jargon in "computer gaming", but only in that particular game (or that particular software, which may not even be a game?).